# Chromium Dev Tools (webkit): How to permanently show Padding-Margin-Border Overlay?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, webkit

When hovering with the mouse over items in the DOM list ("Elements" tab) in Chromium, it shows a very useful overlay in the browser window of margin (orange), padding (green), border (yellow). Same goes for all those individually when hovering over the "styles" window respectively.
The overlay also displays a nice tool-tip with X x Y and class names.

Sidenote: I'm not sure if this is possible at all, and probably applies to all webkit browsers.

Is there any way, this overlay can be made sticky or permanent, so I can move the mouse away from the dev-tools window and scroll the page and still see the same element overlay highlighted?

I've not found and answer on google or SO so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems kinda impossible to do in the current stack. The closest you can get is the "Computed" pane which shows the smaller version of the same view.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I guess "impossible atm" is also a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an chrome-plugin called [Pesticide](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bakpbgckdnepkmkeaiomhmfcnejndkbi), which maybe will help you. It draws borders around all boxes, so you will see the margin and padding.